# Proving that an arithmetic function is multiplicative, but not completely multiplicative?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Define an arithmetic function $\rho$ by $\rho(1)=1$ and $\rho(n)=2^m$ where m is the number of distinct prime numbers in the prime factorization of n. Prove that $\rho$ is multiplicative, but not completely multiplicative.

This is my first introduction to arithmetic functions so I'm not quite sure how to prove these kinds of things. I can plug numbers into the $\rho$ function,  but how can I show this through a formal proof?

Comment: apply the definition and say that $gcd(a,b) = 1 \implies \rho(ab) = \rho(a)+\rho(b)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start you off and see if you can give the proof yourself. Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers, with $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Say $\rho(a)=2^n,\rho(b)=2^m$. You need to show that $\rho(ab)=2^{n+m}$. Consider what the prime factors of $ab$ are, with respect to $a$ and $b$.

To disprove complete multiplicativity, you need $a$ and $b$ with $\rho(ab)\neq\rho(a)\rho(b)$. Since you've proven that $\rho$ is multiplicative, your counterexample should be two positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $\gcd(a,b)>1$. Try a few examples and see if you can find something.

Comment: If $(a,b)=1$ and $\rho(a)=2^n$ and $\rho(b)=2^m$, then $\rho(ab)=2^{m+n}$ because a and b share no primes, correct? How can I show that mathematically?

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN It's pretty direct- the prime factors of $ab$ are the prime factors of $a$, of which there are $n$, and the prime factors of $b$, of which there are $m$. They don't  overlap, so there are at least $n+m$ distinct prime factors of $ab$. Why are there no other prime factors?

Comment: Because $gcd(a,b)=1$?

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN No, that's how we got the fact that they don't overlap. Finish this sentence: if $p$ is a prime and $p|ab$, then...

Comment: Then p divides a or b?

Comment: Exactly, so the only prime factors of $ab$ are those of $a$, and those of $b$, which means that if $x$ is the number of prime factors of $ab$, and $n$ and $m$ are as before, then $x\leq nm$. Since every prime factor of $a$ and every prime factor of $b$ is a prime factor of $ab$, and no prime is a factor of both $a$ and $b$, then $n+m\leq x$. Then $x=n+m$, hence $\rho(ab)=2^{n+m}$. Now just find a pair of integers $c$ and $d$ with a common divisor, and find $\rho(cd).

Comment: I don't understand how $gcd(a,b)=1$ isn't sufficient. If you know that a and b are relatively prime, then they don't share any divisors, so you know that there is no overlap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47094/discussion-between-kevin-long-and-derpypenguin).

Comment: @KevinLong I happen to have the same question, so how can we assume that a and b are relatively prime?

Comment: @JamieJohn A function is multiplicative if $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ whenever $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, so you only care if they're relatively prime. If $a$ and $b$ aren't relatively prime, it's fine for $f(ab)$ to not equal $f(a)f(b)$, so just assume that they are relatively prime.

Comment: @KevinLong Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just show that $\rho(2)^2\ne \rho(2^2)$. Clearly $\rho(2)=\rho(4)=2$, so you're done.

Comment: Is it sufficient to only show one example though?

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN disproving a for all statement is done with a counterexample, yes.

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN Complete multiplicativity of $\rho$ claims that every pair of natural numbers, $a$ and $b$, satisfies $\rho(ab)=\rho(a)\rho(b)$. If you have one counterexample, then it's not true for all natural numbers. To prove multiplicativity, however, you need to show it holds for all natural numbers, so an example wouldn't work.